# Zassenhaus's theorem on sharply 3-transitive groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

I am looking for any modern (and English) reference to the following theorem:

If $G$ is finite group acting sharply $3$-transitively on $1+2^m$ points, then $G \cong {\mathrm{PSL}}(2,2^m)$.

I have looked at Huppert, Endliche Gruppen I, which seems to discuss the aspects on the converse direction (at least until chapter II) unless I am mistaken (my German is not too good). William Kerby's lecture note on "On infinite sharply multiply transitive groups" has it (Thm.10.2), however uses abstractions through skew fields.

I was wondering if there is a self contained proof without too much of details.

Comment: I know this was asked a while ago, so I don't know if you are still interested, but Donald Passman's book $\textit{Permutation Groups}$ covers the classification of finite sharply transitive groups in decent detail including the Mathieu groups. That being said, it isn't exactly modern since it's from the 60s.